# How to control cache in JSP page?

Tags: jsp, caching, servlets, servlet-filters

I created a Servlet filter with the following code in doFilter:

```
HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse)response;

httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache");
httpResponse.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
httpResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); 

chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

I want to make sure that nothing gets cached at the Client and every request (even the one's from the Browser's back button) are directed to the Server.

But, even after implementing the above filter, some pages are cached (accessible using browser's back button).

And other pages that are not cached, show **Web Page Expired** error in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To start, the complete set is:

```
httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
httpResponse.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
httpResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
```

The `no-store` and `must-revalidate` are required to get it to work in under each Firefox.

> *But, even after implementing the above filter, some pages are cached (accessible using browser's back button).*

How did you test it? Those headers will actually prevent the browser from requesting the page from the browser cache instead of directly from the server. Best test is to have a `Filter` to listen on `/*` and add a debug statement in flavor of:

```
HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
String method = httpRequest.getMethod();
String URI = httpRequest.getRequestURI();
System.out.println(method + " request invoked on " + URI);
```

This should print the actual requests.

Also ensure that you don't override the headers in the JSP page itself using the HTML `<meta>` tags.

> *And other pages that are not cached, show **Web Page Expired** error in Internet Explorer.*

You can only get this if the non-cached request was `POST` request, not a `GET` request. The `GET` requests will simply be requested from server again instead of from the browser cache.

Answer (score 4):

I found this in the oracle docs where they mention that you should never use

```
httpResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
```

instead of it you should use

```
setDateHeader("Last-Modified", (new Date()).getTime() );
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13158_01/alui/wci/docs103/devguide/tsk_pagelets_settingcaching_httpexpires.html

Answer (score 0):

We also use the Last-Modified header to encourage the browser to always get a new version.

`setDateHeader("Last-Modified", (new Date()).getTime() ); // Set last modified to right now.`

I'm not sure about keeping the browser's back button from using the cache, though.  Anything that you do with header fields is only going to be evaluated when the page is first loaded, IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this info: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19501-01/819-3659/beagw/index.html (see **The cache Tag**)