# How to clear browser cache from servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, cache-control

When I'm clicking logout button I want the browser cache to be cleared.

I'm trying to clear the browser cache, using the following code:

```
if(uri.equals("/SciArchive/logout.sci"))
    {
        HttpSession session=req.getSession(false);
         res.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache"); 
             res.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store"); 
             res.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); 
             res.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); 
        if(session!=null)
        {
            session.invalidate();
            rd=req.getRequestDispatcher("/home.jsp");               
        }

        rd.forward(req,res);
        return;
    }
```

When back button is pressed in browser window after logout, I need the browser not showing the previous page.

When I'm clicking back button it shows the previous page, after clicking forward button in browser window it shows `document expired`.

Please give me suggestions to clear this error!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot *clear the cache*, but you can ask that your pages will not be cached. This means that you must do so for every page in your session (else the back-button will keep working, and your logout page is the only page not cached).

See also:
[How to control cache in JSP page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953431/how-to-control-cache-in-jsp-page?rq=1):

> ```
> httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
> httpResponse.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
> httpResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
> ```

edit:
Apparently it is possible to *clear the cache* programmatically using javascript and a refresh, but I doubt that this is what you are looking for:
[How to programmatically empty browser cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155064/how-to-programmatically-empty-browser-cache)

Answer (score 1):

```
<%
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

//Forces caches to obtain a new copy of the page from the origin server
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");

//Directs caches not to store the page under any circumstance
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);

//Causes the proxy cache to see the page as "stale"
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
//HTTP 1.0 backward enter code here

String userName = (String) session.getAttribute("plno");
if (null == userName) {
  //request.setAttribute("Error", "Session has ended.  Please logenter code herein.");
  RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("Login.jsp");
  rd.include(request, response);
  out.println("Session has ended.  Please login.");
}
%>
```

This is how to clear the cache in jsp page. It can also set the session's inactive timeout

Comment: What do you mean by "this is the way"?

Comment: Can the cache be cleared using servlet instead of JSP?